# 3-D Plot in MATLAB Containing: Time, Frequency and Power Spectral Density

Tags: matlab, speech-recognition

I am currently working on a project for my Speech Processing course and have just finished making a time waveform plot as well as both wide/narrow band spectrograms for a spoken word in Spanish (aire).

The next part of the project is as follows:

> Make a 3-D plot of each word signal, as a function of time, frequency and power spectral density. The analysis time step should be 20ms, and power density should be computed using a 75%-overlapped Hamming window and the FFT. Choose a viewing angle that best highlights the signal features as they change in time and frequency.

I was hoping that someone can offer me some guidance as to how to begin doing this part. I have started by looking [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html) under the **Spectrogram and Instantaneous Frequency** heading but was unsure of how to add PSD to the script.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to give you an example.

I am going to generate a linear chirp signal.

```
Fs = 1000;
t = 0:1/Fs:2;
y = chirp(t,100,2,300,'linear');
```

And then, I am going to define number of fft and hamming window.

```
nfft=128;
win=hamming(nfft);
```

And then I am going to define length of overlap, 75% of nfft.

```
nOvl=nfft*0.75;
```

And then, I am performing STFT by using spectrogram function.

```
[s,f,t,pxx] = spectrogram(y,win,nOvl,nfft,Fs,'psd');
```

'y' is time signal, 'win' is defined hamming window, 'nOvl' is number of overlap, 'nfft' is number of fft, 'Fs' is sampling frequency, and 'psd' makes the result,pxx, as power spectral density.

Finally, I am going to plot the 'pxx' by using waterfall graph.

```
waterfall(f,t,pxx')
xlabel('frequency(Hz)')
ylabel('time(sec)')
zlabel('PSD')
```

The length of FFT, corresponding to 20ms, depends on sampling frequency of your signal.

EDIT : In plotting waterfall graph, I transposed pxx to change t and f axis.

Comment: Genius. Thanks a bunch!